# Evaluar si una secuencia de dominó es válida o no

Tags: javascript

Tengo este problema:

En el juego de dominó se van poniendo fichas de forma que un número de una ficha coincide con el siguiente. Cada ficha tiene 2 números (del 0 al 6).

Se quiere verificar si la secuencia de fichas colocadas es correcta. La única verificación a realizar es que coincidan el número con la siguiente.

Se asume que no hay fichas inválidas (todas tienen 2 números en el rango indicado separados por ":", entre cada par de fichas hay un espacio, no hay fichas repetidas).

**Ejemplo:** Si se ingresa como secuencua `0:3 3:6 6:2 2:4 4:5`, el programa debe mostrar que **es correcta**.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
let dif = 2;
let dif2 = 4;
let cumple = false;
let secuencia = (prompt("ingrese secuencia"));

while (dif2 < secuencia.length) {
  if (secuencia.charAt(dif) === secuencia.charAt(dif2)) {
    let cumple = true;
    dif = dif + 3;
    dif2 = dif2 + 3;
  }
}
if (cumple = true) {
  alert("es correcta");
} else {
  alert("no es correcta");
}
```

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para recorrer la cadena y saber si cumple la condición. Por algún motivo, ese código no funciona.

Comment: Esto: `if(cumple = true){` esta mal, debería ser así: `if(cumple == true){` o incluso `if(cumple)`

Comment: yo comenzaría por separar cada par de números (en nuestro caso, cada ficha del domino), con `const fichas = secuencia.split(" ");` Luego ya comparaía la ficha 1 con la 2, la 2 con la 3, etc... eso se logra facilmente con un ciclo comenzando en 0 hasta n-2... y cada ciclo compara el elemento n con n+1

Answer (score 0):

Primero separa las fichas de la secuencia (por espacios), luego de obtener cada ficha puedes separarlas en los dos dígitos que la conforman (por los dos puntos). De este modo podrás hacer la validacion de una forma más sencilla.

Puesto que para que una secuencia sea válida, el segundo dígito de la ficha anterior debe de ser igual al primer dígito de la ficha que estás evaluando actualmente. Como ya hemos separado los dígitos de cada ficha entonces eso se traduce a `fichaAnterior[1] === fichaActual[0]`. En caso de que sean dígitos distintos entonces no es una secuencia válida y por tanto ni siquiera deberías preocuparte por seguir evaluando la secuencia.

No es necesario hacer una conversión a número, puesto que la validación de cadena te serive perfectamente.

```js
function validarSecuencia(secuencia) {
  let esSecuenciaValida = true;
  let fichas = secuencia.split(' ');
  if (fichas.length > 1) {
    fichas = fichas.map(f => f.split(':'));

    for (let i = 1; i < fichas.length; i++) {
      const fichaAnterior = fichas[i - 1];
      const fichaActual = fichas[i];
      if (fichaAnterior[1] !== fichaActual[0]) {
        esSecuenciaValida = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return `Secuencia ${esSecuenciaValida ? '' : 'no'} válida`;
}

console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6 6:2 2:4 4:5'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6 6:2 2:4 6:4'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 8:6 6:2 2:4 6:4'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 6:3'));
```

El código anterior asume que toda secuencia es válida, y eso solo cambirá en caso de que en efecto no se trate de una secuencia váilda. Debido a que se menciona que asumas que no hay fichas inválidas, tampoco tienes que preocuparte por llevar un control sobre las fichas, aunque tienes que tener presente de que en caso de presentarse alguna ficha sin uno o dos de sus dígitos, el programa no funcionará.

#### Extra

Otra forma más corta de resolver el problema es usando [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) y aplicando la misma lógica. El método `.every()` devolverá `true` siempre y cuando se cumpla una condición para todos los elementos, en este caso la condición deseada es `fichaAnterior[1] === fichaActual[0]`:

> El segundo dígito de la ficha anterior debe de ser igual al primer dígito de la ficha que estás evaluando actualmente.

En cuanto se retorne un valor no [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (o `false` en este caso), `.every()` retornará `false` y dejará de seguir evaluando al resto de los elementos de forma automática.

Podrías lograr un comportamiento similar con [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), sin embargo al encontrarte con un par de fichas que no cumplan la condición, no podrás detener la evaluación de las fichas subsecuentes, al menos [no de una forma sencilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144406/how-to-early-break-reduce-method).

```js
function validarSecuencia(secuencia) {
  return secuencia
    .split(' ')
    .map(f => f.split(':'))
    .every((fichaActual, i, fichas) => {
      if (fichas.length > 1 && i > 0) {
        return fichas[i-1][1] === fichaActual[0];
      }
      return true;
    }) ? 'Secuencia válida' : 'Secuencia no válida';
}

console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6 6:2 2:4 4:5'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6 6:2 2:4 6:4'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 8:6 6:2 2:4 6:4'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 3:6'));
console.log(validarSecuencia('0:3 6:3'));
```